# DataDog send custom data from RUM

Tags: datadog, rum

I need to send the screen resolution from the user's device through DataDog.
As it is easy to get `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` values, I have no clear idea how to send the values. My idea is to send a custom action:

```
import { datadogRum } from '@datadog/browser-rum';

(function sendScreenSize() {
    datadogRum.addAction('screenSize', {
        'width': window.screen.width,
        'height': window.screen.height
    })
})();
```

Is there any cleaner solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using `beforeSend` to add the width and height to the [event context](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/modifying_data_and_context/?tab=npm#enrich-rum-events) for `view` events, then you will always have that data for each view.

For your current approach, you'd want to call `addAction()` in response to a page load or window resize event.

Comment: Well I am interested to get things only once, I just want to know how many users are using 4k monitors or tablets. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: In that case, to reduce the amount of data you're storing, you could only invoke `addAction` if the resolution is greater than however many pixels wide 4k is. 

But for your case, you could also use a regular count metric and submit via API or SDK rather than tracking this in RUM. https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/metrics/#submit-metrics or https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/node/#metric-collection might help