# Is it possible to get the user screen resolution with Datadog?

Tags: reactjs, datadog

I'd like to know if there's a way to catch the user browser screen resolution with Datadog!

Comment: Here's an answer to a similar question that should point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72115710/656011

Answer (score 0):

Solution: [Send RUM Custom Actions](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/guide/send-rum-custom-actions/?tab=cdnasync)